# SQL Server JDBC connection exceptions for Windows authentication on Windows Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, windows-server-2012

I have a Java servlet running on Tomcat which connected to SQL Server with JDBC. It works fine on a Windows Server 2008.
However, when I deploy the application to another Windows Server 2012 today with same configuration file, I got the following exceptions:

> SEVERE: Invalid connection detected. Renewing database connection.
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\CURRENT_HOST_NAME$'.)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
>       .
>           .
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\CURRENT_HOST_NAME$'.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1LogonProcessor.complete(SQLServerConnection.java:2306)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2534)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1929)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1917)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1061)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
>       ... 27 more

The DOMAIN is the domain name, and CURRENT_HOST_NAME is the the application server host name. My connection URL is: `jdbc\:sqlserver\://DB_SERVER_ADDRESS\\DB_INSTANCE;DatabaseName=DB_NAME;integratedSecurity\=true;`

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems solved some days ago. It was because that new computer didn't have service account running, so SQL server rejected the authentication.